# How to test fetch call to get 100% test coverage

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

Given the file with a single function:

```js
export const fetchGetCard = (lang, word) => {
    return fetch("/getCard", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ lang: lang, word: word })
    }).then(response => response.text())
}
```

How do I create tests using Jest to have 100% code coverage for this file? Or is it worth it to just completely ignore testing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a mock for `fetch()`
2. return from it resolved `Promise`
3. return from it failed `Promise` (error/throw/etc)
4. Check for the returning value from the `fetchGetCard()`
5. Assert expected parameters and values in the underlying objects

If you are using `require()` you can easily mock `fetch()` in multiple ways:

- create a function for the import
- access the cache with `require.cache[require.resolve("fetch")].exports = <your mock>`
- use [SinonJS](https://sinonjs.org/) for mocking, import `fetch()` in your test prior to anything else `myfetch = require("fetch")`, call `const stub = sinon.stub(require.cache[require.resolve("fetch")], "exports")`, do stuff, then restore it with `stub.restore()`